# Question about the numbers of distinct roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K/F$ be a field extension and $u \in K$ algebric over $F$ and $\beta \in F(u) $. Let $f=Irr(u , F)$, the irreducible monic polynomial of $u$ over $F$ , $g=Irr(\beta , F) $, $h=Irr(u, F(\beta)) $ and $L$ be a splitting field of $fg$ over $F$

If $n_f$, $n_g$ and $n_h$ are the number of distinct roots of $f$, $g$ and $h$ in $L$, respectively, how do I show that $n_f =n_g n_h$?

Comment: Is root field the same as splitting field?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes, it is. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think the claim is not true. If you take $F = \mathbb{Q}, K = \mathbb{C}, u = \beta = \mathbb{\sqrt{2}}$, then $f = x^2 - 2, g = h = x - \sqrt{2}$ but $2 = n_f \ne n_g n_h = 1$.

Comment: If $\;\beta\in F(u)\;$ then trivially $\;g=x-\beta\;$ . Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Oh, I edited, the correct would be $g=Irr(\beta, F) $

Comment: @AlexVong I wrote the question wrong, I edited and I think that now is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is separable then $F(u)/F$ is a separable extension. $n_f=F(u):F$ , $n_g=F(\beta):F$, $n_h=F(u):F(\beta)$ Hence we have $n_f=n_g.n_h$. Suppose $f$ is not separable. Then $f(X)=P(X^{p^m})$ where $P(X)$ is separable. Then $n_f=[F(u):F]_{sep}$,  $n_g=[F(\beta):F]_{sep}$,  $n_h=[F(u):F(\beta)]_{sep}$ and hence we have $n_f=n_g.n_h$

Comment: Why $f$ separable implies that $g$ is separable?

Comment: because $F(u)$ is a separable extension.